# Remove string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

In my table `Products` in SQL Server, I have a column `UrlLink` with values that look like this:

```
Id         UrlLink
-----------------------------------
1          domain/product1.html?7
2          domain/product2.html?34
3          domain/product294.html?6576
4          domain/product54.html?765
```

How to remove parameter

```
?7, ?34, ?6576, ?765
```

from column `UrlLink`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the query string part from the UrlLink column in the table, you need to use [Left](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [CharIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) in your UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE Products
SET UrlLink = LEFT(UrlLink, CHARINDEX('?',UrlLink)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Colin Mackay!

Answer (score 2):

Using `left` and `charindex` should work:

```
select left(UrlLink, charindex('?',UrlLink)-1) from Products;
```

This would return everything before the first occurrence of a `?`. You might want to add some null checks if parameter isn't mandatory in the UrlLink column.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to find `?` in your url and take string upto it. You can use `LEFT`/`SUBSTRING` for getting substring and `CHARINDEX` for finding `?` in your string. Check out my query below

```
select id, substring(urllink,1,charindex('?',urllink)-1)
from products
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
DECLARE @myvar varchar(100);  
SET @myvar = 'domain/product1.html?7';  

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING((REVERSE(@myvar)),   (CHARINDEX('?',REVERSE(@myvar))+1),500)) AS result ;  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In case multiple `?` symbols are there in the `UrlLink` column values and if you want to take the value after the last `?` symbol. Then use a combination of **[`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)** and **[`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186323.aspx)** .

**Query**

```
SELECT
  [Id],
  SUBSTRING([UrlLink], 1, 
     LEN([UrlLink]) - CHARINDEX('?', REVERSE([UrlLink]), 1)) AS [UrlLink]
FROM [Products];
```

***[`Demo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/581330/remove-string-in-ms-sql-server)***

Answer (score 0):

- Simple and won't fail in case you have a `Urllink` that does not contain`?`.
- In case of multiple `?` removes everything from the first `?` since in URL this is the only `?` with special significance.

---

```
select      id,left(Urllink,charindex('?',Urllink+'?')-1)

from        Products
```